# How do i Develop a plugin for a VMware product?

Tags: plugins, vmware, vmware-tools

I have a requirement to build a plugin for vRealize operations manager(vROps). This plugin essentially tweaks the existing functionality to make it more customized. How do I develop this plugin?

- By how, I mean do i tweak the source code of the product(Which i doubt i can) or Is there any other way I can add my custom functionalities?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer for this. Turns out you enroll yourself into vmware {code} and get access to the respective SDK. Use this SDK to add your custom functionality and then package it into a plugin.

https://code.vmware.com